# Typo3 bidirectional 1:n Relation

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I have two Models one for category and one for product. A product can have one category and a category can have multiple products.

For every product i can set and retrieve the category but not in the opposite direction. If i want to get all products in a category with
`$category->getProducts()` in a controller or `{category.products}` in a view i only get one product.

What am i missing?

Category Model:

```
    /**
     * products
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistance\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product>
     */
    protected $products = null;

    /**
     * __construct
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        // Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initializeObject();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties when model is reconstructed from DB (where __construct is not called)
     * Do not modify this method!
     * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
     * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeObject()
    {
        $this->products = $this->products ?: new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a Product
     *
     * @param \Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function addProduct(\Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->attach($product);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a Product
     *
     * @param \Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product $productToRemove The Product to be removed
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeProduct(\Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product $productToRemove)
    {
        $this->products->detach($productToRemove);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the products
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product> $products
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the products
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Product> $products
     * @return void
     */
    public function setProducts(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }
```

Product Model:

```
    /**
     * category
     *
     * @var \Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Category
     */
    protected $category = null;
    /**
     * Returns the category
     *
     * @return \Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Category $category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the category
     *
     * @param \Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Category $category
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCategory(\Vendor\Shop\Domain\Model\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }
```

tca category:

```
'products' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:shop/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_shop_domain_model_category.products',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_shop_domain_model_product',
                'foreign_field' => 'category',
            ],

        ],
```

tca product:

```
'category' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:shop/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_shop_domain_model_product.category',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_shop_domain_model_category',
                'minitems' => 1,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ],
        ],
```

view:

```
<td>
    <f:for each="{category.products}" as="product">
      {product}<br>
    </f:for>
</td>
```

ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tx_shop_domain_model_product (
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    prize double(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    quantity int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    category int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);

CREATE TABLE tx_shop_domain_model_category (
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    products int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);
```

Comment: Where are you storing the information of *multiple* assignments? Both sides of your relation are `int(11)`. There's no information about a list of products...
Changing `tx_shop_domain_model_category.products` to VARCHAR should solve this. Then, TYPO3 would be able to save all list of UIDs.

Comment: @JulianHofmann The official doc [link](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/6-Persistence/1-prepare-the-database.html) says both should be int. In the parent the sum of the children is saved and when you add an additional property to the model you have access to the children.

Comment: @JulianHofmann I also tried your suggestion, same result.

Comment: The sum of children is saved, yes - if you have an Intermediate Table. Then the Intermediate Table holds the information of which product-UID has been connected with which category-UID.